# Sufficient condition for a Gateaux differentiable function to be Frechet differentiable.

Tags: functional-analysis, multivariable-calculus, solution-verification, banach-spaces, normed-spaces

> Let $E$ and $F$ be Banach spaces. Let $U \subseteq E$ be an open subset. If $f : U \longrightarrow F$ be a Gateaux differentiable function on $U$ and the mapping $x \mapsto Df(x)$ is continuous at $x_0 \in U$ then $f$ is also Frechet differentiable at $x_0.$

The proof requires **Mean Value Inequality** for Banach space valued functions defined on Banach spaces which is as follows $:$

> Let $E,F$ be Banach spaces and $U \subseteq E$ be an open set. Let $f : U \longrightarrow F$ be a Gateaux differentiable function then $$\|f(x) - f(y)\|_F \leq \|x - y\|_E \sup\limits_{0 \leq \theta \leq 1} \left \|Df(\theta x + (1 - \theta) y) \right \|$$ whenever $[x,y]: = \{tx + (1-t)y\ |\ t \in [0,1] \},$ the line segment connecting $x$ and $y$ lies in $U.$

Now the proof (what I found on my own) of the required theorem goes as follows $:$

Let $h \in E$ and $g : t \mapsto f(x_0+th) -f(x_0) - tDf(x_0)(h).$ Then $g(0) = 0$ and using mean value inequality we get $$\|f(x_0 + h) - f(x_0) - Df(x_0)(h) \|  \leq \|g(1)\| = \|g(1) - g(0)\|  \leq \sup\limits_{0 \leq \theta \leq 1} \left \|Dg(\theta) \right \|\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (1)$$

Since $g$ is Gateaux differentiable in some open subset of $\Bbb R$ we have for any $k \in \Bbb R$ $$Dg(\theta) (k) = k g'(\theta) = k (Df(x_0+\theta h) - Df(x_0)) (h)$$ since $g'(\theta) = (Df(x_0 + \theta h) - Df(x_0)) (h).$ Therefore $$\|Dg(\theta)\| = \|(Df(x_0+\theta h) - Df(x_0)) (h)\| \leq \|h\| \|Df(x_0+\theta h) - Df(x_0)\|.$$  Substituting this in $(1)$ we have $$\|f(x_0 + h) - f(x_0) - Df(x_0)(h)\| \leq \|h\| \sup\limits_{0 \leq \theta \leq 1} \|Df(x_0+\theta h) - Df(x_0)\| = o(\|h\|).$$

This shows that $f$ is Frechet differentiable at $x_0.$

Does my proof make sense? Please check it.

Thanks for your time.